# Is there a way to integrate the FixedColumns plugin with angular datatables?

Tags: angularjs, datatables

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

Currently it does not seem like it supports the FixedColumns DataTables plugin...

Answer (score 1):

This feature is planned for the v0.0.4.
Currently, there is however a [workaround](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/142).

Comment: I believe you mean v0.4.0

Comment: Yes. Typed too quickly. My bad.